# Is there a simple way to restore a backstack of fragments onto a FrameLayout after they've been removed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Say I have a FrameLayout holding a backstack of fragments A -> B, remove them, and then later on use the same FrameLayout to show fragment Z. Assuming I'm done with Z, is there a simple way to restore A -> B onto the FrameLayout?

In short, I've been using a single FrameLayout to show different sets of fullscreen fragments, but there's a case where I need to to restore a specific set of fragments. (A user begins an upload, I close the upload fragment during the upload so the user can continue using the app, the user may open a different fullscreen fragment, and if an error occurs during the upload they need to be able to bring back the upload fragment from where they left off.)

As far as code goes I've been using the following FrameLayout to display fullscreen fragments:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

When I want to show a new fragment I use:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

transaction.replace( R.id.fullscreen_fragment_container, fragment )
.addToBackStack( identifier )
.commit();
```

When I want to move to another fragment while keeping a navigation history I use:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

transaction.replace( R.id.fullscreen_fragment_container, fragment )
.addToBackStack( null )
.commit();
```

When I want a clean slate I use:

```
Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentById( R.id.fullscreen_fragment_container );
transaction.remove( fragment ).commit();

fragment_manager.popBackStack( identifier, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE );
```

Comment: Did you read the blog post about [multiple back stack support in Fragments](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Oh that does look promising thank you. I'll have to try it once it's out of alpha. That verifies there's currently not some standard way to do this which is good to know (I didn't want to start rolling my own implementation just to find out there's a simple technique to it.)

Comment: [Fragment 1.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.4.0) is stable now :)